# Stop Nokogiri from removing new lines

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I'm trying to strip out all html from a string so I can perform some regexes on it. I discovered you can use Nokogiri to get the text by using xpath like so:

```
Nokogiri::HTML(my_string).xpath("//text()").text
```

This works quite well, but I have found that it removes some new line characters almost randomly, which ends up breaking my regular expressions. The html it receives is always valid (although often not well formed - it was made using a wysiwyg editor) so that shouldn't be an issue.

Is there a reason that Nokogiri would remove the new lines and is there a way to avoid it? This is for a command line script, so I don't have rails or anything else.

here's a sample of the text where it's not preserving newlines:

```
<p>Composition: <span>83% Polyester Bright, 17% Spandex &nbsp; &nbsp;</span>&nbsp;<span><br />
 </span>Washing: Cold hand wash only<span><br />
 </span>Designer: James Lillis&nbsp;<span><br />
 </span>Made in: Australia&nbsp;</p>
```

If it matters, I am reading the html in from a JSON file using Oj. This is how it appears in the JSON file:

```
"\u003Cp\u003EComposition: \u003Cspan\u003E83% Polyester Bright, 17% Spandex \u0026nbsp; \u0026nbsp;\u003C/span\u003E\u0026nbsp;\u003Cspan\u003E\u003Cbr /\u003E\n \u003C/span\u003EWashing: Cold hand wash only\u003Cspan\u003E\u003Cbr /\u003E\n \u003C/span\u003EDesigner: James Lillis\u0026nbsp;\u003Cspan\u003E\u003Cbr /\u003E\n \u003C/span\u003EMade in: Australia\u0026nbsp;\u003C/p\u003E\n"
```

And this is how it ends up when i put it through the above nokogiri function call:

```
Composition: 83% Polyester Bright, 17% Spandex     Washing: Cold hand wash onlyDesigner: James Lillis Made in: Australia
```

Thanks for any help

**UPDATE**: I've discovered that it appears to remove the newlines when the `\n` character is in a span element (which for some reason, the editor did a lot). If there is a way to stop this from happening, I'd like to know, otherwise I'll probably try to detect it beforehand.

Comment: What @pguardiario said is important -- it's hard to help you here without an example of what you're dealing with.  Also, unless I'm mistaken, being well-formed is a requirement for being valid, so I'm unclear about your claim that your documents are always valid but not always well-formed.

Comment: Not well formed was probably the wrong term to use - it just has a load of random spans and such like a wysiwyg editor usually does

Comment: Yes, it's malformed. Those newlines are not allowed. It's libxml for the record, not nokogiri that's responsible for cleaning that stuff up.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I ended up going through and removing those before trying to grab the text and that solved everything.